# Changing from container to container-flud class on tablets with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently using `container` in my project and would like to find a nice way of changing it to `container-fluid` or at least changing the width similar to `container-fluid` when the site is accessed on a tablet, in order to use the width of the device rather than shrinking it.

Do i need to use `@media`-queries for this and alter the `container` class?

What would be best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between `.container` and `.container-fluid` is that the `.container` has an explicit `width` which is set by `@media` queries.

Therefore, you could override it by `width: auto` on specific screen sizes by using `@media` queries.

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/jukew/2/edit)**

```css
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and down) */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .container { width: auto; }
}
```